# Set default from a list in LINQ

Tags: linq

I have the following LINQ for my task -

```
return IEnumerable<MyLDRObject> result = agreementLinesData.Zones
                                            .Where(a => accessibleProductLine ==a.ProductLine)
                                            .Where(b => b.Zone.Contains("CHEST") ||
                                                        b.Zone.Contains("COLLAR") || 
                                                        b.Zone.Contains("WAIST") ||
                                                        b.Zone.Contains("RLOWERARM") || 
                                                        b.Zone.Contains("LLOWERARM") ||
                                                        (isParticipantPregnant == true && 
                                                             b.Zone.Contains("FETAL")))
                                            .OrderBy(a => a.Description) 
                                            .Select(a => new MyLDRObject { Key = a.Zone, DisplayName = a.Description });
```

How can I set a default value to be selected if `isParticipantPregnant == true`?

Thanks
Supratik

Comment: Please format code properly. Also, you can't have `return IEnumerable` in C#. What does "set a default value to be selected" mean?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, you want to set a Default value to Key and/or DisplayName if the property isParticipantPregnant is true. If this is it, so all you need is a lambda expression in the select.

```html
Select(a => new MyLDRObject { 
Key = isParticipantPregnant ? "defValue" : a.Zone, 
DisplayName = isParticipantPregnant ? "defValue" : a.Description 
})
```